# how to position text properly in html without &nbsp; after 2003? I had a long break in frontend works

Tags: html, css, frontend

Back in  the 2003, when my templates where cut into a tables, I used   to position all the text how I wanted.

I know it's a newbie question and I should probably take some beginner css courses, but the question is - how to position text with as little fuss as possible like that:

```html
start at 0 px &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; start at 100px&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;                                      start at 300px
```

Comment: You need to start by doing exactly what you already said: go over the basics, read up on HTML5, CSS3, etc. Take some online classes https://www.codecademy.com/learn/web. You won't be able to do much until you do this. If you want to position text that's all related (so it's in the same `<p>` I'm assuming), then you'll need to wrap the positioned text inside of an element, `<p>Normal text <span>positioned text</span></p>` and then use CSS to "position" the span with padding. Or, if this is actually tabular data, then use a `<table>`.

Answer (score 1):

For the example you post in your question, I would go about it something like this:

```css
span {
display: inline-block;
}

span:nth-of-type(1) {
width: 99px;
}

span:nth-of-type(2) {
width: 199px;
}
```

```html
<span>Start at 0px</span>
<span>Start at 100px</span>
<span>Start at 300px</span>
```

Answer (score 1):

HTML

```
<div class="item start0">
   start at 0px
</div>
<div class="item start100">
   start at 100px
</div>
<div class="item start300">
   start at 300px
</div>
```

CSS

```
.item{
   float:left;
}
.start0{
    width:100px;
}
.start100{
    width:200px;
}
.start300{
    width:100px; // example
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Width is the best bet. If you're going to use a div, you need to float left or the divs will be pilled up.